# CMake does not compile a c file in C++ project even after I set the C file language to CXX

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to link SQLite with my project. To do so, I do this in cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(SQLITE++ VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SQLITE3_HOME "src/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3360000")
set(SQLITE3_CORE_C "${SQLITE3_HOME}/sqlite3.c")
# Tell CMake to compile this with C++ compiler
set_source_files_properties(SQLITE3_CORE_C PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )

file(GLOB sqlitepp_SRC "src/**.cpp")
add_library( sqlite3++ STATIC
    ${SQLITE3_CORE_C}
    ${sqlitepp_SRC}
)
```

Problem is, this does not work and I get errors like these:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close_v2
```

Notably, I have a Visual Studio project set to build the same sources and it works fine.

SQLite headers do set `extern "C"` in them so that's not the cause. I have also put deliberate nonsense into `sqlite3.c` that would crash the compilation. I see no errors, meaning the file is not compiled at all. Putting wrong filename for it causes an error, so the file is seen, but not added to build.

Comment: You forgot to dereference variable `SQLITE3_CORE_C` in `set_source_files_properties` call.

Comment: The shown cmake does not invoke a linker, thus the shown linker error is unrelated to the cmake file.

Comment: @273K Who invokes a linker in their CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: The only target is a static library, that does not invoke a linker for building.